# perl script to match comma

Tags: regex, perl

I have a netlist generated from schematic. This netlist includes power pins. Iam trying to write a perl script to remove power pins from netlist. 
As part of this i have to search for  a string that matches the pattern shown below:

```
", );"
```

I have used the following code and it is not working

```
$line =~ s/,\s+\);//g
```

I have observed that pattern end with comma are matched but pattern starting with comma or pattern with comma in middle are not matched.
Any suggestions on how to get this work

Comment: you need to escape the `)` the pattern should be `,\s*\);`

Comment: `$line =~s/\,\s*\)\;//gs;`

Comment: @ssr1012: What's the `/s` for?

Comment: In case of any enter mark might be

Comment: @ssr1012 `/s` only changes the meaning of `.`. There is no `.` in this regex.

Comment: @ssr1012 i have already tried this and it did not work for me. In perl, comma need not be escaped.

Comment: Please show your data, what is currently happening, and what you want to happen. In other words, create a little perl script that sets $line to something , modifies $line, and then prints $line. Where $line prints something other than what you want, put a comment that indicates what you want it to print.

Comment: @Mani: Comma is also one of the operator in perl, some cases we need to check on this.

Comment: My verilog file is below.       `timescale 1ns / 1ps 

module SigGen ( Sig, dvdd, dvss, Event, Inp, RB );
output  Sig;

inout  dvdd, dvss;

input  Event, Inp, RB;



bufx4 I2 ( .VSS(dvss), .VDD(dvdd), .VSUB(cds_globals.sub_), .Y(Sig),
     .A(net23));
invx1 I1 ( .VSS(dvss), .VDD(dvdd), .VSUB(cds_globals.sub_), .Y(E),
     .A(EB));
invx1 I3 ( .VSS(dvss), .VDD(dvdd), .VSUB(cds_globals.sub_), .Y(EB),
     .A(Event));
Latchr I0 ( .Q(net23), .QB(net24), .D(Inp), .E(E), .EB(EB), .RB(RB),
     .VSS(dvss), .VDD(dvdd));

Comment: My perl code to remove supplies is LOOP1: while(<FP>)
{
my $line = $_;
(my $line = $_) =~ s/\),\n/\),/g;
$line =~ s/\.VDD\(\w+\),//g;
$line =~ s/\.VSS\(\w+\),//g;
$line =~ s/\.VSUB\(\w+\.\w+\),//g;
$line =~ s/\s+\.VDD\(\w+\)//g;
$line =~ s/\),\s*\)/\)\)/g;
print "$line\n";
printf DP $line;
}                                         The stand alone line for comma matching works but when i use it with the other matching patterns, it does not work.

Comment: Please update these in your questions not in comment

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this instead:

```
s/,\s*\);//
```

You should be defensive and be able to handle no whitespace between the `,` and the `)`. You have to escape the `)`. See `perldoc perlre` for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But the problem is not with matching a space, it is with matching comma, when the pattern starts with comma.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one. I have found the problem. The problem was that the pattern to be recognized is split in to two different lines. The "," is in one line followed by ");" in next line. At first, iam removing the new line character and assumed that the next line will get appended to the current line, which is not happening. Hence, the pattern matching did not work.

To resolve this, i have to read the file once again and then replace the pattern.